# TypeError: Tag.find_all() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import random

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.zillow.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' + str(random.randint(1, 1000)), #IF YOU RATELIMIT AND GET CAPTCHA, CHANGE USERAGENT
}


with requests.session() as i:
    #user input
    city = str(input("City To Search In: ")) + "/"

    #initializers
    page = 1
    end_page = 10
    url = ""
    url_list = []
    request = ""
    request_list = []

    while page <= end_page:
        url = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/" + city + str(page) + "_p"
        url_list.append(url)
        page += 1

    for j in url_list: #can change j to "url" if you want but i like "j" for simplicity
        request = i.get(j, headers=headers)
        request_list.append(request)

#another two initializers (seperating this felt more organized to me, sorry if it looks messy)
rawInfo = ""
rawInfoList = []

for r in request_list: #can change r to "request" if you want but i like "r" for simplicity
    rawInfo = soup(r.content, "html.parser")

    rawInfoList.append(rawInfo)

cleanedList = []

for rawInfo in rawInfoList:
    for i in rawInfo:
        address = soup.find_all (class_= "list-card-addr")
```

This is some code I am using to scrape info from zillow search pages. Wheen I use soup.find_all to find all of the addresses listed from the raw info I pulled, it gives this error: "TypeError: Tag.find_all() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'". Anyone know what I did wrong?

I was expecting it to spit out all of the addresses it found in the first 10 pages of results. You can do print(rawInfoList) to see the raw info.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please think carefully about the structure of the code. Where the code says for rawInfo in rawInfoList:`, what do you think will be the value of `rawInfo` each time through the loop? What type will it have? (Hint: when you created the list, you added items with `rawInfoList.append(rawInfo)`, right? What was `rawInfo` at that point in the code? What does `rawInfo = soup(r.content, "html.parser")` mean?) Therefore, what should you do with the `rawInfo`, in order to get information from the page?

Comment: Where the code says `soup.find_all (class_= "list-card-addr")`, what do you think this means? Specifically, what do you expect `soup` to be at this point in the code? Why should it be possible to use `.find_all` with that?

Comment: I'm looking back and feeling pretty stupid. It should be `i.find_all (class_= "list-card-addr")`. I'm trying to get it to find any addresses in the raw info.